# Distinguishing between the same web elements with Python Selenium based on relates

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

After third attempt of solving this problem, I am unable to finalize this on my own. I would appreciate, if someone would like to share their thoughts on the following issue.

Let us assume, we have such kind of HTML structure:

```
<div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="title"></div>
        <h3 class="title">HEADER NUMBER ONE<h3>
    <div class="area"></div>
        <div class="something">IO field</div>
            <input class="input"></input>
            
<div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="title"></div>
        <h3 class="title">HEADER NUMBER TWO<h3>
    <div class="area"></div>
        <div class="something">IO field</div>
            <input class="input"></input>
```

My intention is to identify an input element that belongs to the second panel.

Based on reliability check, when I have hardcoded XPATH gathered directly from the browser, sometimes wrong element is being identified (I assume that there are many scripts running when the page is being loaded, which impacts the reliability and stability). Therefore I would like to distinguish between elements based on the h3, which are the one and only difference between objects.

How can I do it?

When identifying elements one by one (so first the title, then its parent, and then moving down to the input), I receive an "element not interactable" exception which is not dependent from the time.

I am thinking of something like:

```
find //input[@class='input'] where one of ancestors contains /div/h3 which contains(text(), 'HEADER NUMBER TWO')
```

Obviously, I did not found any working solution for that, despite I spent more than a week with that.

Is it doable at all? If so, could you suggest me something, please? The structure in real is a little bit more complex, but I need just a pattern, hint, or clue.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate the parent `panel` element based on it's child `h3` with the desired title and then to locate the `input` element inside it.
The XPath to do so can look like the following:

```py
"//div[@class='panel' and(.//h3[contains(.,'HEADER NUMBER ONE')])]//input"
```

Or even

```py
"//div[@class='panel' and(contains(.,'HEADER NUMBER ONE'))]//input"
```

The selenium command using that XPath can look like:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='panel' and(contains(.,'HEADER NUMBER ONE'))]//input")
```

**More explanations**
The XPath

```py
"//div[@class='panel' and(.//h3[contains(.,'HEADER NUMBER ONE')])]//input"
```

literally means:
Find element with `div` tag and `class` attribute value `panel` and having some child element inside it (this is `.//` comes for) containing `HEADER NUMBER ONE` text content.
Inside the above `div` element find `input` child element.

Comment: I would not come up with that on my own. It is pretty complex to understand, but it means that I still large amount of knowledge to possess.

Thank you. It works.

I really appreciate the speed, accuracy and details included in your answer. Thank you very much! All the best!

Comment: Well, this is a bit complex XPath, right. But not something impossible to understand. Also I hope I described it. In case you need more explanations - let me know.

Comment: It is fine, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium you can find a set of elements:

```
inputs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS, 'input[class="input"]')
input_2 = inputs[1]
```

The input you need is the 2nd element in the list